# Can't startup Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm just trying to setup a tomcat server. I got the following setting:

Tomcat 9 installation inside: `/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1`
WebAppliction located at: `/srv/appsiting-dev/`

Structure of the WebApplication:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 root appsiting 4096 Jan 15 20:08 bin
drwxrws--- 2 root appsiting 4096 Jan 16 18:52 doc
drwxrwsr-x 2 root www-data  4096 Jan 16 19:48 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Jan 15 19:56 log
drwxrwsr-x 2 root appsiting 4096 Jan 15 19:56 php-lib
drwxrwsr-x 2 root appsiting 4096 Jan 16 02:38 public_html
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root      4096 Jan 15 19:57 tmp
drwxrwsr-x 7 root root      4096 Jan 16 00:45 tomcat
drwxrwsr-x 3 root appsiting 4096 Jan 15 21:30 var
drwxrwsr-x 2 root appsiting 4096 Jan 15 19:57 zend-app
```

Inside the tomcat directory there is the following:

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 appsiting appsiting 4096 Jan 16 20:25 conf
drwxrws--- 2 appsiting appsiting 4096 Jan 16 20:07 logs
drwxrwsr-x 2 appsiting appsiting 4096 Jan 16 20:20 temp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root      3015 Jan 16 00:45 tomcat
drwxrwsr-x 7 appsiting appsiting 4096 Jan 15 23:32 webapps
drwxrwsr-x 2 appsiting appsiting 4096 Jan 15 23:32 work
```

`tomcat`is a start-up script. I got the following inside of my `tomcat.conf`, which is located inside of `conf`

```
USERNAME="appsiting"
PORTBASE="40000"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$(($PORTBASE+2))"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintClassHistogram"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
export JAVA_OPTS

export JAVA_HOME="/usr"
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1"
export CATALINA_BASE="/srv/appsiting-dev/tomcat"
```

So when I startup my server I get a `tomcat.err` and a `catalina.out`. And even though the `tomcat.err`tells me the Tomcat has started, catalina.out doesn't have a "Server starup in xx ms" inside of it.

tomcat.err

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /srv/appsiting-dev/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /srv/appsiting-dev/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-    9.0.0.M1/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /srv/appsiting-dev/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Tomcat started.
```

catalina.out is empty. Here is the start up script as well: 
https://www.refheap.com/113725

When running it I'm getting a

```
sudo ./tomcat start
Starting Tomcat (appsiting-dev) ............................... failed.
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Java ?

Comment: `mak@rs000868:~$ java -version`

`java version "1.7.0_91"`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Isn't Tomcat 9 designed to need Java 8 minimum ? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.0.M1_(markt)

Comment: Hmm, yeah you are right. I updated to openjdk-8-jre but still get the same error.

Comment: Alright had another problem with my ports, now eveything is fine! Cheers for the java version clue though!

Answer (score 1):

local host port is already using in other service or process.find and kill(stop) it.

Comment: How would I do that?